# Появление по очереди а не сразу всех линий

Tags: javascript

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

var alpha = 0;
canvas.globalAlpha = alpha;

function draw() {
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.moveTo(0, 0);
  canvas.lineTo(10, 0);
  canvas.stroke();
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.moveTo(20, 0);
  canvas.lineTo(30, 0);
  canvas.stroke();
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.moveTo(40, 0);
  canvas.lineTo(50, 0);
  canvas.stroke();
  alpha += .01;
  canvas.globalAlpha = alpha;
  if (alpha < 1)
    setInterval(draw, 200);

}

draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Скорее тут нужно `setTimeout`, чтобы не постоянно интервалить, а только 1 раз, ко всему этому нужно каждую линию делать через тайм-аут.

Comment: Я так и подумал, но не будет ли это слишком громостко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'), lines = [
    [0, 0, 10, 0, 333, .4],
    [20, 0, 30, 0, 600, .25],
    [40, 0, 50, 0, 1500, .6]
];
lines.forEach(array => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        canvas.globalAlpha = array[5];
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.moveTo(array[0], array[1]);
        canvas.lineTo(array[2], array[3]);
        canvas.stroke();
    }, array[4]);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```